# ¿Cómo puedo traer el contenido de un html/php que se encuentra en otro archivo?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web y quiero hacer una **header** que va a quedar en varias de las paginas de la web, pero no sé que método podría usar y que sea efectivo, yo intente hacerlo con un `include`, pero me salta el siguiente error:

> Warning: include(\Jomar\users_control\views\header\header.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\users_control\views\control_asistencia\index.php on line 180
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '\Jomar\users_control\views\header\header.html' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\users_control\views\control_asistencia\index.php on line 180

Así que, si alguien tiene un método más eficiente para hacer lo que quiero, o alguna forma de arreglar mi problema, por favor ayúdenme.

Aquí hago el `include`

```
<?php 
        include '/Jomar/users_control/views/header/header.html'; 
?>
```

Aquí se observe el `html` abierto con la url

[image: html]

Aquí el directorio

[image: Directorio]

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la línea en la que haces el `include` y, de ser posible una imagen que muestre el árbol de directorios de tu proyecto... El error claramente dice que no encuentra el archivo o el directorio, así que es posible que se trate de un error de ruta de archivo.

Comment: Listo, ahí tienes, y lo que te digo, es raro porque el directorio está bien

Comment: Quizá puede ser la mezcla de barras para directorios *nix (/) y las de Windows (\\). Prueba con  `include '\Jomar\users_control\views\header\header.html';`

Comment: Por favor, puedes colocar la estructura de tus directorios donde tienes el proyecto. Porque por lo que veo estas incluyendo **jomar** que es el directorio de tu proyecto y si usas **incluede** este no te hace falta ya que el **include** trabaja con los directorios de adentro. una cosa mas estas usando algún framework.

Comment: @LógicoSoftware Es lo primero que intenté, y nada

Comment: ¿@DaxTter77 y con el full path o usando relativos al archivo con .\?

Comment: @YoelRodriguez lo maneje desde los directorios de esta manera `include '../header/header.html'` pero no funcionó, por eso lo hice así, no uso frameworks, ya te muestro la estructura

Comment: Por favor puede colocar la imagen de las estructura de tus directorios la que tiene en el explorador.

Comment: @LógicoSoftware full path, no, y lo otro sí

Comment: @YoelRodriguez ya lo puse

Comment: El fichero que estas haciendo el **include** en que directorio esta por favor si puedes coloca el código completo de donde haces el include

Comment: Está en el `/views/control_asistencia/index.php`

Comment: En **control_asistencia** esta dentro de esta ruta **/users_control/views** si es así prueba de la siguiente manera: `inlcude "..header/header.html"`

Comment: Así lo hice originalmente y no me dio, por eso ahora lo tengo como se muestra ahí

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97074/discussion-between-yoel-rodriguez-and-daxtter77).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me tocó buscar mucho y es hasta ahora lo único que me ha funcionado, el método es con `jquery`, con el `load()` coloqué las etiquetas `<header></header>` y con el `$(selector)` de `jquery` señalé el `header` e hice el `load()`y listo, lo cargó ahí, dejó el ejemplo aquí

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("header").load("/Jomar/users_control/views/header/header.php");
    });
</script>

<body style="background-color:#800D0D0D">
    <header>
    </header>
</body>
```

Gracias por la ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer estas accediendo erroneamente al archivo header.html, prueba esto:

```
 <?php 
        include '../header/header.html'; 
 ?>
```

[image: php include example]

Comment: Sí, ya la intenté

Comment: Pero la cuestión es que el html donde hago el include ya tiene codigo

Comment: para ir descartando que sea otro el problema, coloca ambos archivos en el mismo directorio y cambia el include 'header.html';

Comment: Sí, funciona, pero ahí es donde pierde sentido lo que hago, tendría que copiar el archivo de **header** y meterlo en cada una de las carpetas de las **views** en las que lo voy a usar y es casi como copiar el código en cada una de ellas

Comment: Entonces prueba colocando el path completo, yo uso linux, en tu caso con windows deberia ser asi : include 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Jomar/users_control/views/header/header.html';

Comment: Pues, lo intenté, y como era de esperarse, no funcionó

Answer (score 2):

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo de cómo funciona un `include` con `PHP`, luego lo adaptas a tu estructura... *Si tu proyecto se llama **Jomar** y el archivo `PHP` está ubicado en la raíz de este directorio, sería: `include '/users_control/views/header/header.html';`*

Suponiendo que mi proyecto se llama **inclusion**: en la raíz del directorio, pongo mis archivos `header.html` y `footer.html`. Adicionalmente, tengo un directorio llamado **vista** que contiene el archivo `prueba.php` y `otro.php`... los archivos contienen las siguientes líneas de código:

**header.html**

```
<header>
    <strong>Este sería el header de todas tus vistas</strong>
</header>
```

**footer.html**

```
<footer>
    <strong>Este sería el footer de todas tus vistas</strong>
</footer>
```

**prueba.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba</title>
    </head>
    <?php
        //Con ../ le estoy diciendo que se salga del directorio vista para que
        //encuentre el archivo header.php (así ubicas la ruta)
        include '../header.html';
    ?>
    <body>
        <br>
        <h1>Este es el contenido de tu vista actual!</h1>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
    </body>
    <?php
        include '../footer.html';
    ?>
</html>
```

**otro.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Otro</title>
    </head>
    <?php
        include '../header.html';
    ?>
    <body>
        <br>
        <h1>Este es el contenido del archivo otro!</h1>
        <img src="http://ximg.es/600x400/000/fff">
    </body>
    <?php
        include '../footer.html';
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso es lo que he estado haciendo

Comment: Pero supongo que mi error debe estar en la ubicación de mi archivo, así que tendré que moverlo a ver sí me da

Comment: No, nada, ya lo intenté moviendo el archivo y nada

Comment: Si tienes el código como lo muestras en las imágenes del [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97074/discussion-between-yoel-rodriguez-and-daxtter77), lo estás haciendo mal. `header.php` no debe contener toda una estructura `html`, solo debe contener el código con las etiquetas `<header>contenido del encabezado</header>`. El archivo `index.php`, por su parte, no debe contener las etiquetas `<header></header>` encerrando el `include`, solo debe llevar el `<?php include '../tuRuta'; ?>`  como te muestro en mi ejemplo.

Comment: Sí, y justamente acabo de hacer los cambios y no me funciona

Comment: veo que tu `index.php` está en la ruta: `views/empleado/index.php` y tu `header.php` está en: `views/header/header.php`... siendo así, el `include` debe quedar así: `<?php include '../header/header.php'; ?>`. Con esto le estoy diciendo que se salga de **empleado** (para que quede en **views**, luego que entre a la carpeta **header** y tome el código de **header.php**

Comment: Sí, así lo he puesto y nada

Answer (score 0):

depende de como quieres traer los datos si es de un archivo seria asi
sencillo..

```
$file_dirrectory = "include/html/";
$nombre_archivo = foot.html;
//la siguiente varible leera el archivo en cuestion
     template_file = fread($file_directory, filesize($nombre_archivo));

// a continuacion cerramos el directorio
                 fclose($file_directory);
// creamos una nueva variable para obtener un par y ver cual nos funciona mejor
                  action_theme = template_file;
                  action_theme = str_replace ("'", "\'", action_theme);
aquí probamos
        print(template_file);
```

Answer (score -3):

puedes utilizar iframes en el archivo principal y poner en la propiedad src la ruta de los php y html que quieres incluir

```
src="example.html"
```

agregando-----

tu quieres que el header (cabecera) se visualice en todas tus paginas entonces tu puedes crear un iframe para la cabecera en todas tus paginas y para llamar al contenido de tu cabecera solo pones la ruta de tu archivo ya sea html o php, por que el "require" solo sirve para importar código php , no funciona con HTML , y con el iframe si puedes llamar varias veces un HTML

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres exactamente, podrías explicarte mejor

Comment: tu quieres que el header (cabecera) se visualice en todas tus paginas entonces tu puedes crear un iframe para la cabecera en todas tus paginas y para llamar al contenido de tu cabecera solo pones la ruta de tu archivo ya sea html o php, por que el "require" solo sirve para importar código php , no funciona con HTML , y con el iframe si puedes llamar varias veces un HTML