# require_once no encuentra archivo por culpa de (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php, xampp

Llevo varios días con un error de `PHP` y no encuentro la solución.
El caso es que hasta que Windows se actualizó todo funcionaba correctamente pero a partir de la actualización, dejó de funcionar.

Tengo un proyecto con `PHP`, y en mi `index`, tengo un `require_once` de la siguiente forma:

```php
<?php 

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/app/controllers/tools/ControllerFactory.class.php';

    echo ControllerFactory::createController()->render(); 
 ?>
```

Pero cuando entro me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: require_once(/app/controllers/tools/ControllerFactory.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \index.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/app/controllers/tools/ControllerFactory.class.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in \index.php on line 10

Estoy usando xampp y tengo un enlace simbólico en la carpeta `C:\xampp\htdocs` a una carpeta que tengo dentro de OneDrive para que se sincronice el proyecto con la nube y como he dicho, antes de actualizar Windows esto funcionaba sin problema.

Además, he comprobado que el enlace no se haya roto tras la actualización, no se ha roto:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 <mi usuario> <mi usuario>       53 Jul 15 20:36 htdocs -> '/mnt/c/Users/<mi usuario>/OneDrive/webs'
```

He estado buscando y decían que podría ser por culpa de que el archivo php.ini no estuviese bien configurado ([Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658/getting-pear-to-work-on-xampp-apache-mysql-stack-on-windows)) y yo creo que lo tengo bien configurado, al menos la ruta que me sale en el error, es correcta con la carpeta donde se encuentra la carpeta PEAR.

También por las rutas relativas, por eso le he puesto lo de "dirname(__FILE__)." delante de la ruta. ([Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602454/require-once-path-cant-locate-file))

Decir también que no estoy usando Laravel, es PHP vainilla.

muchas gracias a todos.

**Edito**

El error debe venir por el enlace simbólico y los permisos de la carpeta ya que si añado al require la función `realpath()` el error que me da cambia a:

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\php\pear): failed to open stream: Permission denied in \index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in \index.php on line 17

Además, si el proyecto lo meto en la carpeta htdocs directamente sí que funciona.
He estado revisando los permisos de la carpeta y creo que son correctos, ya que en teoría cualquier usuario podría ejecutar el script.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 <mi usuario> <mi usuario> 1321 Aug  3 00:40 ControllerFactory.class.php
```

También he comprobado que el problema lo tiene al hacer el require ya que los scripts sin requires los ejecuta correctamente.

He probado a desactivar el antivitus y el firewall, pero tampoco funciona.
No sé si es alguna protección que ha añadido Microsoft con la última actualización.

Comment: hiciste un `echo  dirname(__FILE__).'/app/controllers/tools/ControllerFactory.class.php';` antes del require_once para ver que imprime com ruta completa?

Comment: Intenta también con el "\" de esta manera `\app\controllers\tools\ControllerFactory.class.php`

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` se puede abreviar como `__DIR__` , prueba con `realpath(__DIR__  . '/app/controllers/tools/ControllerFactory.class.php' )` tal vez no esté reconociendo el punto de montaje del symlink. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: Hola Juan, sí hice un `echo dirname(__FILE__).'/app/controllers/tools/ControllerFactory.class.php';`, copié la ruta que salió en el navegador, y se mostró el archivo `ControllerFactory.class.php` por lo que la ruta debe ser correcta.

Comment: Cambiar el símbolo "/" por "\" tampoco me funcionó. 

He probado a poner realpath y ahora el error que me da es:
`Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\php\pear): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <ruta>`. He mirado los permisos de la carpeta y tiene permisos de ejecución para todos los usuarios.

Comment: A mi me pasó lo mismo, pero al momento de hacer un include, pero es exactamente el mismo error, y no lo pude resolver, el problema es que la solución que yo usé, no creo que te sirva a ti, ya que lo que yo necesitaba era pues abrir un archivo html y dejarlo como header

Comment: Aquí te dejo [Mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283882/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-traer-el-contenido-de-un-html-php-que-se-encuentra-en-otro-archivo) y mira las respuestas y comentarios que me hicieron a ver si de pronto te puede ayudar

Comment: Hola @DaxTter77, lo tuyo fue muy inteligente, lo que no pudiste traer con PHP lo conseguiste con una llamada Ajax al archivo. A grandes problemas grandes soluciones, pero sí, como indicas yo no puedo hacer lo mismo ya que yo necesito que el intérprete de `php` ejecute el script sí o sí.
¿A ti se te ha actualizado el ordenador hace poco? ¿Usas enlaces simbólicos? A mi si quieto el enlace simbólico me va bien, pero pierdo la sincronización con OneDrive. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, estoy pensando que a lo mejor es un bug de xampp (Extraño porque eso sí que no lo he tocado)

Comment: @Pedro debe de serlo, sino hubiese encontrado esa forma, estaría todavía en eso, o ya me hubiese rendido, realmente no se ha actualizado que yo sepa, aunque este es el de la empresa, pero yo soy el único que lo maneja, así qué lo dudo, pero pues solo me dio problemas ahí

Comment: Si consigo encontrar la solución la postearé aquí como respuesta a mi pregunta pero por ahora nada de nada. Y en la información que encuentro, o el error es distinto o la solución no me funciona.  :/

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente solucioné el problema volviendo a instalar XAMPP y creando el enlace simbólico de nuevo.