# Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Funciones.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\pear.')

Tags: php, xampp

para solventar el error con el cual titulo esta pregunta
intente revisando, encontre varios del mismo error en foros su solución, no funciono o lo aplique mal yo entonces a continuación dejare lo que intento hacer para que salte el error como también lo que intente para tratar de solventar el error en cuestión [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mismas preguntas con sus soluciones que puede bien aplicar mal

lo primero fue reinstalar todo sigue igual
[require_once no encuentra archivo por culpa de (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285621/require-once-no-encuentra-archivo-por-culpa-de-include-path-c-xampp-php-pear)

lo segundo modificar el php.ini que encuentra en C:\xampp\php o por el xampp Control Panel
apache config php.ini   cambiando la siguiente lineas
Fix the part of the line that says, "\xampplite\php\pear\PEAR" to read "C:\xampplite\php\pear".
intente con comillas simples dobles punto sin punto sin comas  también aclaro que  en lugar de xammpplite solo xampp decía .
https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/7242

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despúes intente ver si el php.ini era  el correcto  ejecutando http://localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php
como sugiere en :
https://techlandia.com/obtener-archivo-phpini-xampp-como_203249/

pero me encuentro con que el phpinfo.php no está si accedo por http://localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php reviso xampp  los unicos que encuentro son :

[image: phpinfo.php encontrados]

no se que estoy haciendo mal o si me pase por alto algo
desde ya se agradecen las respuestas.

Comment: Una pregunta, y los estilos si te los esta aplicando ??

Comment: Y al poner la ubicación completa, el problema se solventa? Quizás solo sea problema de la dirección relativa.

Comment: ¿Desde el navegador ingresas directamente al _index.php_ de la carpeta `Vista/html`?

Comment: si colocara todo en la misma carpeta funciona correctamente pero al modularizar se presento este problema al dividir en carpetas como lo expone la captura en pantalla que muestra el include  ahora probando lo que comentas  no no carga los estilos, probé también la ruta completa pero mismo error sin cambios, si entro al index.php por http://localhost sigue el error pero si lo arrastro al index.php desde Vista/html  carga todo normalmente los estilos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es "culpa" de la variable de ambiente `include_path`, PHP la consulta solo en caso de no encontrar el archivo que se desea incluir; lo que está pasando aquí es que inicias la ejecución desde otra ruta, de acuerdo a tu estructura, parece ser:

```
- Super/
-- index.php  // Aquí es donde ingresas
-- Controlador/
---- Funciones.php
-- Vista/
---- html/
---- index.php // Aquí es donde se presenta el problema
```

Cuando accedes directamente a `Super/Vista/html/index.php`, efectivamente, requieres subir dos niveles para acceder a *Super* y de ahí a *Controlador*, sin embargo, al ingresar por `Super/index.php` **PHP toma como carpeta por defecto la del script que se está ejecutando** y lo mantiene para todos los scripts que incluyas.

Cuando incluyes `/Super/Vista/html/index.php`, conserva como carpeta por defecto `/Super` y, la ruta para acceder, sería directamente `./Controller/Funciones.php`, pero corres el riesgo de errores en el futuro, por acceder desde otra ruta.

Puedes aprovechar que todas las peticiones inician desde el mismo *script* (`/Super/index.php`) y definir un par de constantes, una para directorio (include) y otra para URL (estilos y enlaces):

/Super/index.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Si vas a usar sesiones, siempre debe ir primero
// Definir ruta base para incluir archivos
define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__);  // c:/xampp/htdocs/Super
// Definir url base para estilos y enlaces
define('BASE_URL', ''); // http://tu_host_virtual
```

**Nota:** Si no estás usando "Virtual host" y accedes directamente desde `http://localhost/Super`, entonces la ruta URL debería ser: `define('BASE_URL', '/Super');`

Después usas esas constantes para incluir archivos o enlazar estilos.

/Super/Vista/html/index.php

```
<?php
// Incluir archivo
include_once BASE_DIR . '/Controlador/Funciones.php';

// Enlazar estilos
?>
<link src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/Vista/css/menu.css">
```

**Importante:** Si vas a tener otros puntos de acceso aparte de *index.php*, entonces tal vez te convenga crear un archivo *config.php* para guardar estas variables, junto con información para conectar a base de datos e incluirlo desde cada punto de acceso.

Comment: si entendi  bien la estructura del config.php seria ? en el mismo archivo donde defino las direcciones  define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__);  este archivo config.php estaria en la carpeta raiz llamada Super? entonces solo llamo del index asi include_once BASE_DIR . ahora te consulto porque  tengo todas las funciones en Funciones.php tengo declarada la conexión como global en ese mismo archivo como entonces para ocupar como si fuese un framework desde  config.php declaro la direccion de  funciones.php pero las funciones defino una por una como si estuviera en django ?

Comment: Me refiero a que podrías tener constantes para conexión como DB_HOST, DB_USER, etc., que después usarías para establecer tu conexión sin tener que hacer más modificaciones en `funciones.php`